# Using one image png file for retina and normal screen in UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, retina-display

Say there is cool.png file with dimension 200 X 100 pixels and I'd like to use it for both retina and normal devices. 
I need to get size of UIImageView 100 X 50 points.

I tried to decrease the size of UIImageView according to image dimensions and visually I don't see any difference whether I prepare two file with and without scale modifier @2x or use UIImageView to scale it by contentMode property.

```
BOOL retina = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0 ? YES : NO;

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cool.png"];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

CGFloat width = img.size.width;
CGFloat height = img.size.height;

if (!retina) {
   width = width/2.0;
   height = height/2.0;     
}

imgView.frame = CGRectMake (somePoint.x, somePoint.y, width, height);
```

Is there something wrong in the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the wrong approach here..

CGRect,Point and Size aren't measured in pixels.. They are points.. Points are iOSes coordinate system and will be scaled to the device... So for example if you make a UIView 320 points wide then it will fill the width on both a retina iPhone or iPad...

so if you want your cool.png to display at 100x50 points on all devices then you can simply set the frame to be 100x50, set the image to cool.png then set the imgView.contentView to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit... This will then rescale the 200x100 image to fit of its a non retina device... Then if it was a retina device it would be at full resolution (200x100) but in the 100x50 points...

However the @2x system was made for a reason as having to scale the images down increases loading times as it has to be scaled but if you can't use @2x images then you can still do the above

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You're right, I overlooked that size of UIImage is in points.